# Set a content type's teaser image (right outlined)

Tags: media, ubercart, nodes

So I'm looking to get the image of the teaser display from the bottom outlined to the right. Here's screenshots to make it clearer.

[image: This is what I've got]

[image: This is what it should look like]

As you can see, I've already managed to do it once, but I can't reproduce.
Also, can't find how to get the "add to cart button" on the product.

Comment: Are you theming this directly in the template file? Or using a series of views and Panels?

Comment: yes, I'm only using views.. That's how I got it done the first time. So should i look in the css files maybe?

Answer (score 0):

What you will want to do is go to your views admin page for that view.

If the view is built using fields simply click on that field and select:

1. Style Settings
2. Check the box titled "customize field HTML"
3. You can modify the view to display it as a div or leave it as is
4. Check the box titled "create a css class"
5. Type in a css class
6. Click apply. And save the view.

Now you can go to your theme .css file and create a new css rule to position the image. And should apply for all future views with that css class for that field.

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: The view does not use fields ("The selected style or row format does not utilize fields.") I should be able to get it done without css actually. But css shouldn't be a problem. You know of any other way of custom styling what I've already got? thanks already Cromian

Comment: Well if you wanted to do it manually you will need to build the view out so that the image is always on the right (prob a bit more time consuming and far more complicated). If you cant do fields then with firebug you can locate that DIV/Image and set a .css class style that item. But HTML will always by default show items left justified unless you add some style guide.